# Make an NSWindow (or something else) appear above the menubar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to create an NSWindow (or something else) that can appear above the mac menubar. I know this is possible because TeamViewer does it with their "mouse" image.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iZbG.png

How do they do it? (or, how can I do it?)

Comment: Not an answer, but take a look at window levels. ( http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html ). Anyhow, you generally don't want to break with such a basic UI principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to check out [window levels](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as alluded to in moritz' comment.  Any level above NSMainMenuWindowLevel should appear above the menu bar.

If you really want to be above everything else, you can use a shielding window level (not technically part of the regular NSWindow window level).  Shielding windows are intended for full screen apps which take over the screen, but you can use a regular window which does this.  I have a magnifying glass type app that uses this to good affect.

```
[myWindow setWindowLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()];
```

Also as alluded to moritz' comment, doing this is generally a bad idea, so make sure you've a good reason for doing so.

Comment: yeah the reason why I'm doing it is similar to your magnifying glass and TeamViewer's mouse.